# Storing data to SQL not working with my sql connector and scrapy

Tags: python, sql, scrapy, mysql-python

I am trying to store my scraped data with scrapy to a SQL database but my code does not send anything while no error is mentioned when runned.

I am using my sql connector since I don't manage to install MySQL-python. My SQL database seems to running well and when I run the code the traffic KB/s raise. Please find below my pipelines.py code.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

class CleaningPipeline(object):
    ...

class DatabasePipeline(object):

    def _init_(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = 'root',
            passwd = '********',
            database = 'lecturesinparis_db'
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mdl""")
        self.curr.execute("""create table mdl(
                        title text,
                        location text,
                        startdatetime text,
                        lenght text,
                        description text,
                        )""")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        return item

    def store_db(self, item):
        self.curr.execute("""insert into mdl values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (
            item['title'][0],
            item['location'][0],
            item['startdatetime'][0],
            item['lenght'][0],
            item['description'][0],
        ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the class in `ITEM_PIPELINES` first to let the scrapy know i want to use this pipeline.

In your `settings.py` file Update the lines below with your class name as following.

```
# https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'projectname.pipelines.CleaningPipeline': 700,
    'projectname.pipelines.DatabasePipeline': 800,
}
```

The numbers 700 and 800 shows in which order the pipelines will process data, it can be any integer between 1-1000. Pipelines will process items in the order based by this number, so pipeline with 700 would process data before the pipeline with 800.

**Note**: Replace the projectname in `'projectname.pipelines.CleaningPipeline'` with your actual projectname.